# Text search with Spring Data Redis

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data, jedis, spring-data-redis

I am trying to find documentation around creating and searching a text index on redis using Spring Data. I see @Indexed but dont find @TextIndexed like with Spring data MongoDB.

https://github.com/RedisLabs/JRediSearch

Answer (score 0):

There's no Redis module support in Spring Data Redis and we don't plan to add support for Redis modules.